# How to get from a 7-folder-deep directory structure to a 3-folder structure for TMS?

Tags: tilecache

so I got a Tiled Map Service up and running using TileCache to store all my tiles and OpenLayers to actually show them in a browser using an Apache server. But the demo map tiles I found were stored in a 7 folder deep directory, e.g.

```
13/000/002/123/000/004/936.jpg
```

would be zoom level 13, column 2123, row 4936. But I've been given tiles formatted just 3 folders deep, e.g.

```
13/2123/4936.jpg.
```

I'm guessing the first, 7-segment is the TMS standard since it worked correctly and everything displayed correctly, but I was wondering if there was any easy fix to display the 3-segment directory correctly, or am I just going to have to change it to fit the 7-folder format? And is there any easy way to do that? Because that'd be a lot of files to have to change. Thanks.

Comment: So I'm guessing they have this longer format because windows folders can only hold so many files? Still looking for any kind of answer though!

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.  The answer is easy but the documentation made it non-obvious.

Simply change the cache type to GoogleDisk.

[cache]
type=GoogleDisk

Found the answer here: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/SOLVED-Combine-Mapnik-generate-tiles-py-w-TileCache-td3965126.html